# Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error from SQS SendMessage

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am constructing my own REST calls for SQS SendMessage Action. 
All the parameters for SendMessage are in request body. (QueueUrl, Action and MessageBody).

I have created my own signature calculation code(mostly copied from AWS SDK Java).

Now, when my MessageBody="HelloWorld" , it works fine. 
That means my signature calculation and credentials are correct.

But, when I insert a space , MessageBody="Hello World", I am getting a 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch error from SQS.
I also tried "Hello%20World" as MessageBody , but that also returns a 403 error.

Also tried "Hello+World". But got same error.

I found that aws sdk converts spaces to '+' before calculating the hash of payload.

I tried MessageBody="Hello.World" and that also worked perfectly.

Is there any issue with spaces in Message Body ?

I am sending Host and x-amz-date as the only headers in my request.

The error response from SQS suggests that the hash of the payload is the only thing different in the actual and expected canonical request.

Comment: You are doing a `POST` request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`... is that correct?  Encode the post body as `Hello%20World` **and** use that exact same value when signing the request... don't sign one thing and actually send another, in this case.

Comment: Doing this exactly.

Comment: Before calculating the hash of the request payload , do we have to encode it ?
I tried to replace space with "+" before calculating the hash and it worked.


I tried to use URLEncoder.encode(payload, "UTF-8") before calculating the hash of the payload. But that also didn't work.

So, what is the exact encoding required for the request payload before calculating the hash of it ?